# How can I delete "a lot" of rows from a dataframe in r

Tags: r, delete-row

I tried all the similar posts but none of the answers seemed to work for me.  I want to delete 8500+ rows (by rowname only) from a dataframe with 27,000+. The other columns are completely different, but the smaller dataset was derived from the larger one, and just looking for names shows me that whatever I look for from smaller df it is present in larger df.  I could of course do this manually (busy work for sure!), but seems like there should be a simple computational answer.

I have tried:

```
fordel<-df2[1,]

df3<-df1[!rownames(df1) %in% fordel

l1<- as.vector(df2[1,])

df3<- df1[1-c(l1),]
```

and lots of other crazy ideas!
Here is a smallish example: df1:

```
Ent_gene_id clone57_RNA clone43_RNA_2   clone67_RNA clone55_RNA
ENSMUSG00000000001.4    10634   6954    6835    6510
ENSMUSG00000000003.15   0       0       0       0
ENSMUSG00000000028.14   559     1570    807     1171
ENSMUSG00000000031.15   5748    174     4103    146
ENSMUSG00000000037.16   37      194     49      96
ENSMUSG00000000049.11   0       3       1       0
ENSMUSG00000000056.7    1157    1125    806     947
ENSMUSG00000000058.6    75      304     123     169
ENSMUSG00000000078.6    4012    4391    5637    3854
ENSMUSG00000000085.16   381     560     482     368
ENSMUSG00000000088.6    2667    4777    3483    3450
ENSMUSG00000000093.6    3       48      41      22
ENSMUSG00000000094.12   23      201     102     192
```

df2

```
structure(list(base_mean = c(7962.408875, 947.1240794, 43.76698418 ), log2foldchange = c(-0.363434063, -0.137403759, -0.236463207 ), lfcSE = c(0.096816743, 0.059823215, 0.404929452), stat = c(-3.753834854, -2.296830066, -0.583961493)), row.names = c("ENSMUSG00000000001.4", "ENSMUSG00000000056.7", "ENSMUSG00000000093.6"), class = "data.frame")
```

I want to delete from df1 the rows corresponding to the rownames in df2. 
Tried to format it, but seems no longer formatted... oh well....

Suggestions really appreciated!

Comment: What specifically are you trying to delete? Is there a certain pattern in these rownames that you are looking for?

Comment: Hi @Alison Rattray, Welcome to SO!  Can you add a sample of your data?  For instance, use ```dput(head(df2,10))``` to show the first ten rows of your date and do the same for ```df3```? You can paste that into questions using the "edit" option on the bottom left.

Comment: `df1[!rownames(df1) %in% rownames(fordel),]`?

Comment: Please do not post an image of code/data/errors: it cannot be copied or searched (SEO), it breaks screen-readers, and it may not fit well on some mobile devices. Ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3358272 (and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please just include the code or data (e.g., `dput(head(x))` or `data.frame(...)`) directly.

Comment: r2evans... that seemed so promising (and an obvious omission on my part) but gave me back df1 intact... I have attached pics of the dataframes.

Comment: Alison, I think you're much more likely to get help if you heed the suggestions by both @RussThomas and myself: please post the output from `dput(head(df1))` (same for `df2`) in your question. You mention "row names" but nothing is given or shown in the images. Also, make sure your samples are representative in that *some* of `df1` is present in `df2`; not *all*, not *none*. But forgive me for not wanting to transcribe your data-images and guess that they do or do not have actual rownames.

Comment: Might I suggest learning how to improve the readability of your question? It would be good to not have to rely on benefactors to re-edit your question in order to make it readable. https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting

Comment: For formatting ... highlight each frame  (e.g., from `Ent_gene_id` through `192`) and press `Ctrl-K`. Or put three backticks (`\`\`\``) both before and after the data.

Comment: ```> dput(head(df2,10))
structure(list(base_mean = c(7962.408875, 947.1240794, 43.76698418
), log2foldchange = c(-0.363434063, -0.137403759, -0.236463207
), lfcSE = c(0.096816743, 0.059823215, 0.404929452), stat = c(-3.753834854, 
-2.296830066, -0.583961493)), row.names = c("ENSMUSG00000000001.4", 
"ENSMUSG00000000056.7", "ENSMUSG00000000093.6"), class = "data.frame")```

Comment: I added your `df2` to your question, you should put it there instead of in comments (comments can be easily missed by readers, and if there are a lot of comments, many will be hidden ... so the question should be completely self-sufficient).

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned row names but your data does not include that, so I'll assume that they really don't matter (or exist). Also, your `df2` has more column headers than columns, not sure what's going on there ... so I'll ignore it.

### Data

```r
df1 <- structure(list(Ent_gene_id = c("ENSMUSG00000000001.4", "ENSMUSG00000000003.15", 
"ENSMUSG00000000028.14", "ENSMUSG00000000031.15", "ENSMUSG00000000037.16", 
"ENSMUSG00000000049.11", "ENSMUSG00000000056.7", "ENSMUSG00000000058.6", 
"ENSMUSG00000000078.6", "ENSMUSG00000000085.16", "ENSMUSG00000000088.6", 
"ENSMUSG00000000093.6", "ENSMUSG00000000094.12"), clone57_RNA = c(10634L, 
0L, 559L, 5748L, 37L, 0L, 1157L, 75L, 4012L, 381L, 2667L, 3L, 
23L), clone43_RNA_2 = c(6954L, 0L, 1570L, 174L, 194L, 3L, 1125L, 
304L, 4391L, 560L, 4777L, 48L, 201L), clone67_RNA = c(6835L, 
0L, 807L, 4103L, 49L, 1L, 806L, 123L, 5637L, 482L, 3483L, 41L, 
102L), clone55_RNA = c(6510L, 0L, 1171L, 146L, 96L, 0L, 947L, 
169L, 3854L, 368L, 3450L, 22L, 192L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-13L))
df2 <- structure(list(Ent_gene_id = c("ENSMUSG00000000001.4", "ENSMUSG00000000056.7", 
"ENSMUSG00000000093.6"), base_mean = c(7962.408875, 947.1240794, 
43.76698418), log2foldchange = c(-0.36343406, -0.137403759, -0.236463207
), pvalue = c(0.00017415, 0.021628466, 0.55924622)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

### Base

```r
df1[!df1$Ent_gene_id %in% df2$Ent_gene_id,]
#              Ent_gene_id clone57_RNA clone43_RNA_2 clone67_RNA clone55_RNA
# 2  ENSMUSG00000000003.15           0             0           0           0
# 3  ENSMUSG00000000028.14         559          1570         807        1171
# 4  ENSMUSG00000000031.15        5748           174        4103         146
# 5  ENSMUSG00000000037.16          37           194          49          96
# 6  ENSMUSG00000000049.11           0             3           1           0
# 8   ENSMUSG00000000058.6          75           304         123         169
# 9   ENSMUSG00000000078.6        4012          4391        5637        3854
# 10 ENSMUSG00000000085.16         381           560         482         368
# 11  ENSMUSG00000000088.6        2667          4777        3483        3450
# 13 ENSMUSG00000000094.12          23           201         102         192
```

### dplyr

```r
dplyr::anti_join(df1, df2, by = "Ent_gene_id")
#              Ent_gene_id clone57_RNA clone43_RNA_2 clone67_RNA clone55_RNA
# 1  ENSMUSG00000000003.15           0             0           0           0
# 2  ENSMUSG00000000028.14         559          1570         807        1171
# 3  ENSMUSG00000000031.15        5748           174        4103         146
# 4  ENSMUSG00000000037.16          37           194          49          96
# 5  ENSMUSG00000000049.11           0             3           1           0
# 6   ENSMUSG00000000058.6          75           304         123         169
# 7   ENSMUSG00000000078.6        4012          4391        5637        3854
# 8  ENSMUSG00000000085.16         381           560         482         368
# 9   ENSMUSG00000000088.6        2667          4777        3483        3450
# 10 ENSMUSG00000000094.12          23           201         102         192
```

---

**Edit**: same thing but with row names:

```r
# update my df1 to change Ent_gene_id from a column to rownames
rownames(df1) <- df1$Ent_gene_id
df1$Ent_gene_id <- NULL
# use your updated df2 (from dput)
# df2 <- structure(...)
df1[ !rownames(df1) %in% rownames(df2), ]
#                       clone57_RNA clone43_RNA_2 clone67_RNA clone55_RNA
# ENSMUSG00000000003.15           0             0           0           0
# ENSMUSG00000000028.14         559          1570         807        1171
# ENSMUSG00000000031.15        5748           174        4103         146
# ENSMUSG00000000037.16          37           194          49          96
# ENSMUSG00000000049.11           0             3           1           0
# ENSMUSG00000000058.6           75           304         123         169
# ENSMUSG00000000078.6         4012          4391        5637        3854
# ENSMUSG00000000085.16         381           560         482         368
# ENSMUSG00000000088.6         2667          4777        3483        3450
# ENSMUSG00000000094.12          23           201         102         192
```

Comment: Okay, my original files definitely have rownames, but I guess I just pasted the top few rows for this.  Will try this with properly set up files.... sorry about that.

Comment: While row names should always be unique, if you have a column that is guaranteed to be unique (is `Ent_gene_id` unique for each row?) and common between them, then the effect is the same. If not, then you certainly need to post representative data (that includes row names) and/or demonstrate why using my [`rownames` comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57615114/how-can-i-delete-a-lot-of-rows-from-a-dataframe-in-r/57615871#comment101685706_57615114) does not work. Perhaps you did not use `df1 <- ` before that comment (i.e., reassigning the value)?

Comment: OK here is something more akin to how I set up the data in the first place.  The rownames are unique because I had to delete several rows of duplicates and the had no trouble setting up a DESeq2DataSet.

Comment: df1 <- Toy1[,2:5]\n
rownames(df1) <- Toy1[,1]\n
rownames(df1)\n
df2 <- Toy2[,2:5]\n
rownames(df2 <- Toy2[,1])\n
df3 <- df1[!rownames(df1) %in% rownames(df2),]\n
df4 <- df1[!df1$Ent_gene_id %in% df2$Ent_gene_id,]\n
df5 <- dplyr::anti_join(df1, df2, by = "Ent_gene_id")\n

Comment: Tried to add newlines well at least you can tell what row goes where... how can you format data on this web site???

Comment: That code gave me the following:   df1 13 observations of 4 variables
df2 3 observations of 4 variables
df3 13 observations of 4 variables
df4 0 observations of 4 variables

Comment: Will try to properly format everything from now on.  Thanks for the tips!!!

Comment: Alison, I provided a link for how to format on this website, here it is again: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting. And *please*, no non-trivial code/data in comments ... they format horribly.

Comment: ```> dput(head(df2,10))
structure(list(base_mean = c(7962.408875, 947.1240794, 43.76698418
), log2foldchange = c(-0.363434063, -0.137403759, -0.236463207
), lfcSE = c(0.096816743, 0.059823215, 0.404929452), stat = c(-3.753834854, 
-2.296830066, -0.583961493)), row.names = c("ENSMUSG00000000001.4", 
"ENSMUSG00000000056.7", "ENSMUSG00000000093.6"), class = "data.frame")```

Comment: Thanks a ton for the link, will help a lot!  Knew it wasn't right from post#1 but had no idea how to fix it.  Trying to tab just sends the comment!